# How to convert a domain account to a local account

Tags: windows-7, domain, domain-controller, local

I have a Windows 7 laptop that was connected to a Windows domain controller. The domain controller is no longer in operation and has been shut off. The laptop, now stand alone, works fine, but I want to know the impact of keeping the account that I use as a domain account even though it will never rejoin that particular network.

Additionally, I would like to know how to convert my domain account into a local account. I have read a few entries here, but they all seem like they are related to older versions of the OS.

Ultimately, I don't want to reconfigure all of my applications; which I have fine tuned to my liking and workflow. Creating a local account from scratch would mean that I have to re configure all of my apps and in some cases reinstall.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a local account and copying the profile across to the new user? Ideally, take a disk image before you start changing things.

Comment: @Andrew copying profile as files would not do, SID mismatch, paths mismatch, etc. But Googling for the task reveals a 3rd party tool for the migration. Few links mentioning its use: http://tekinaka.com/migrate-an-ad-user-profile-to-a-local-user-acco‌​unt and http://itekblog.com/windows-7-convert-domain-user-local-user and https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2882-disconnect-from-domain-and-keep-user-profile-for-local-user

Answer (score 9):

I've used Windows Easy Transfer to move a local account to a domain account, and I'm certain the reverse could be done. Best of all it's free and built into Windows 7. You can find it  [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer).

You can also do it this way:

- Reboot computer
- Login as a local admin
- Right-click "My Computer", choose Properties
- Advanced User Settings, User Profiles Settings, click "Settings"
- Highlight the previous user, click "Copy To"
- In the "Copy To" dialog box, browse to the profile of the new user and click ok on the "Browse" dialog box.
- In the "Copy To" dialog box, Permitted to use section, click "Change" and add the local user and click "OK".
- Then Click "OK" in the "Copy To" dialog box and "OK" all the way out.

I'm trying to think of any major impacts of using the domain account but since logon caching is enabled you'll always be able to get into the machine. I would still create a local account, copy my settings, then disjoin from the domain (assuming you have local admin access)

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use Windows Easy Transfer to convert the domain account to a local account on the same machine (without copying the profile to a non-local location) and Windows Easy Transfer kept saying it couldn't find the computer!  haha - go figure.

However, I found [these directions](http://itekblog.com/windows-7-convert-domain-user-local-user/) and downloaded application called `[Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html)' and ran it.  It took literally less than one minute and I restarted the computer.  When it came online I saw at the login screen my local profile and logged in and bam!  I was astounded - there was my domain profile set as a local profile.  Then I un-joined the machine from the domain. It worked perfectly, was easy and fast.

I went and checked out how the c:\users directory looked.  I saw the local profile that I made from the domain profile and it all looked good.  In fact, this computer had the `documents` folder set to a different drive and even that worked correctly.

This was a perfect solution.

If you have old profiles that you want to delete, [these directions will serve](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/34252-windows-how-to-delete-user-profiles-in-windows-7).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this does not convert the domain user to a local user. It migrates file and (perhaps) registry settings from the domain user to the local user, but you still end up with a different SID.

This means that anything in the system that is SID-based (file system permissions, SQL server access using Windows Authentication, etc.) will still only refer to the domain user.